# Relationship between custom post type and page/single templates

Tags: php, custom-post-types

I'm trying to create a relationship between my custom post type, "Movie" and multiple page and single templates. The idea is for each page to query "Movie" and display different content from the post.

For example, I have Movie-A with meta information & downloadable files. I want site.com/information/movie-a to display the meta information, and site.com/downloads/movie-a to display the downloadable files.

I know I could create a bunch of post types for each information type and only pull what's needed; but that would require the user to create a bunch of post instead of having all of it under one location.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using custom taxonomies for your custom post type? I assume your custom post is called Movies. You could then create taxonomies containing the information required. i.e. genre, age rating, etc.

Here's a good explaination, have a look over it and see if it suits your requirements:

[A quick guide to creating custom taxonomies in wordpress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/)

Also, I hate to be that person, but if you google something along the lines of "wordpress custom post type movies" you will find that movies are a commonly used example in how to tutorials. It might give you some ideas on how to proceed.

Update, I forgot to add info on the download option you asked about. You can a add a custom meta box to your custom post type (there are other tutorials out there along similar lines)

[Attaching Files To Your Posts Using WordPress Custom Meta Boxes](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/attaching-files-to-your-posts-using-wordpress-custom-meta-boxes-part-1--wp-22291)
 If that's too tricky there are also plugin options.

Comment: I ended up using ACF's relationship meta to link movies to these pages. Not exactly what I wanted since it requires an extra click; but it works just fine in the end